# Variables with For..Next Loops

Tags: visual-studio, combobox, listboxitem

My j is the problem. VB is asking me to declare it but thats not what i want. Im trying to add all if not already in a listbox from combo box. And at the end saying how many i have added.

```
       'Delcare
    Dim bolItemFound As Boolean
    Dim intCounter As Integer

    'Adding all items not already listed
    For i = 0 To lstToPackItems.Items.Count - 1
        For j() = 0 To cboStandardToPackItems.Items.Count - 1
            If lstToPackItems.Items.Count < 0 Then
                lstToPackItems.Items.Add(cboStandardToPackItems.Items)
            End If
            Exit Sub
            If lstToPackItems.Items(i).ToString.ToUpper = cboStandardToPackItems.Items(j).ToString.ToUpper Then
                bolItemFound = True
            End If
            Exit Sub
        Next
        If bolItemFound = False Then
            'add item
            intCounter += 1
            lstToPackItems.Items.Add(cboStandardToPackItems.Items(j))
            MsgBox("You have successfuly added " & intCounter & " item(s) to your list box!")
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
For j() = 0 To cboStandardToPackItems.Items.Count - 1
```

you should not have parentheses after the `j`.